# Android WebView.setDownloadListener - mimetype is always empty

Tags: android, webview

I have android app with WebView and I want to offer better filenames for downloaded files. For example when user want to download "https://stackoverflow.com/" which is html page, i would append .html to filename. I'm using DownloadListener to capture the downloading event for that:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, 
                                String userAgent,
                                String contentDisposition, 
                                String mimetype,
                                long contentLength) {
    Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "url=" + url + " mimetype=" + mimetype, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ... here I download file using DownloadManager
}
```

The problem is that mimetype is always empty string. Also userAgent and contentDisposition are empty and contentLength is -1. The url is correct and it is downloaded without problems.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, I'm guessing extension from url, using .html for url ending with /

Comment: I believe this issue is related to the version of the webview.  Upgrading Chrome/Webview seems to resolve this.